# Missing Wagtail Streamforms Migrations Breaking Heroku Deployments

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I'm not able to deploy to Heroku because of a "models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration" message. My application migrations are current. The problem is that, for some reason, a migration for the wagtailstreams package in the following directory wasn't deployed:

```
.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtailstreamforms/migrations/
```

I tried adding `MIGRATION_MODULES = {'wagtailstreamforms': 'myapp.wagtailstreamforms_migrations'}` to my base.py, running `makemigrations wagtailstreamforms` and deploying again but Heroku still did not run any migrations and still reported that the same model had changes not reflected in a migration.

What is the strategy for updating migrations in libraries like wagtailstreamforms which are not part of my git directory?

Answer (score 0):

I ran makemigrations wagtailstreamforms with Migration_Modules enabled and then again without it, and then once more with Migration_Modules enabled, and pushed to Heroku each time and on the last push the model changes message finally disappeared. Hope this helps someone because I spent a lot of time on it.